# d3 render polygon from points array

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js, polygon

I am rendering a polygon using **d3** and points string, like that:

```js
shapes.enter()
.append("polygon")
.attr("points", function(d) {
    return d.path; // string of points ("123.123 22.334 ....")
});
```

I have the points in an array and I'm using `array.join(" ")` to get the string path.

The problem is that I have lots of points and the join is a heavy operation.

- Is there a way to pass the **array** itself into the points attribute without generating the string path?
- Or else if you have tips how to convert efficiently the array of floats into string path?

---

**answer:**

Eventually, we divided the array to subarrays and joined each one by itself to string, at the end we concatenate all the strings.
Somehow it was faster than any other thing we have tried to do.

Comment: Clearly you need to eventually give a string, not an array. And Array.join(" ") is a priori the best way of joining elements of an array... maybe you need to think about your data: why do you need so many points, and can you go around this? (e.g. have fewer points when the user zooms out, and more points but for a smaller region when the user zooms in....)

Comment: You could use the SVG DOM to add the points without the string conversion.

Comment: @laurent - Thanks, if there will be no choice I will have to decrease the number of points.

Comment: @RobertLongson - Can you give me more details?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/shapes.html#InterfaceSVGPolygonElement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, we divided the array to subarrays and joined each one by itself to string, at the end we concatenate all the strings.

Somehow it was faster than any other thing we have tried to do (array.join the whole array or string concatenation for each element)